# Moving to the last line of a file while reading it in a .each loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I'm reading in a file that can contain any number of rows.

I only need to save the first 1000 or so, passed in as a variable "`recordsToParse`".

If I reach my 1000 line limit, or whatever it's set to, I need to save the trailer information in the file to verify `total_records`, `total_amount` etc.

So, I need a way to move my "pointer" from where ever I am in the file to the last line and run through one more time.

```
file = File.open(file_name)

parsed_file_rows = Array.new
successful_records, failed_records = 0, 0
file_contract = file_contract['File_Contract']
output_file_name = file_name.gsub(/.TXT|.txt|.dat|.DAT/,'')

file.each do |line|
  line.chomp!
  line_contract = determine_row_type(file_contract, line)

  if line_contract
    parsed_row = parse_row_by_contract(line_contract, line)
    parsed_file_rows << parsed_row
    successful_records += 1
  else
    failed_records += 1
  end

  if (not recordsToParse.nil?)
    if successful_records > recordsToParse
      # move "pointer" to last line and go through loop once more
      #break;
    end
  end

end
store_parsed_file('Parsed_File',"#{output_file_name}_parsed", parsed_file_rows)
[successful_records, failed_records]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IO.seek` with `IO::SEEK_END` to move your pointer to the end of the file, then move up to the last CR, then you have your last line.

This would only be worthwhile if the file is very big, otherwise just follow the `file.each do |line|` to the last line or you could read the last line  like this `IO.readlines("file.txt")[-1]`.

The easiest solution is to use a gem like elif

```
require "elif"

lastline = Elif.open("bigfile.txt") { |f| f.gets }
```

It reads your lastline in a snap undoubtedly using seek.

Comment: `IO.readlines("file.txt")[-1]` is not a scalable solution. The OP doesn't know how big the file will be, and `IO.readlines("file.txt")` will read every line into memory before trying to access the last one.

Comment: hoi Tin Man, i was still editing and with your correction the rest of my text was lost but thanks anyway. about your remark, that is why i say that is only usable if the file is not big, i advise the elif solution and if you rather have no extra gems the IO.seek solution

Comment: Yea the reason for this whole ordeal is because the files have been to big to read into memory so we are passing in an argument around 1000

Comment: @Geoff, what solution did you use at last ? could you accept one of the answers or provide your own please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times I'd take advantage of the OS's `head` and `tail` commands using something like:

```
head = `head -#{ records_to_parse } #{ file_to_read }`.split("\n")
tail = `tail -1 #{ file_to_read }

head.pop if (head[-1] == tail.chomp)
```

Then write it all out using something like:

```
File.open(new_file_to_write, 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts head, tail
end
```